# Dynamic prefix attribute PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have a question about attributes in PHP.

I have various Class with the same attributes, but with with different prefix.

Example:

```
$attr->a_field;

$attr2->b_field;
```

So, with another Class I want to access to them.

I tried:

```
$field = "{$prefix}_field";
$attr->{$field}
```

and it works perfect. But is any other way to doing this?

I tried also with:

```
$attr->{$prefix}_field;
$attr->{$prefix}{"_field"};
$attr->"{$prefix}_field";
```

etc and who I suppose I get PHP's errors

Thanks!

Comment: `$attr->{$prefix.'_field'};`

Answer (score 1):

You can write it directly as `$attr->{"{$prefix}_field"}`, as shown in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking into [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
$attr->{$prefix."_field"}
```